# Javascript returning undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to get the value of a spinner and display its value. Here is the spinner code:

```
<div id="site_content">
    <div id="content">
        <h:body>
            <h:form>
                <div class="whiteSpace" />
                <p:spinner id="minutes" min="0" max="1000" value="#{printerSettings.t}" size="1">
                    <p:ajax update="NewTime" />
                    <f:validateLongRange minimum="1" maximum="1000" />
                </p:spinner>
                <h:message id="minutes2" for="minutes" style="color:red" />
```

and here is the javascript code that is called, when the user presses submit

```
function Thankyou() {
    var minuteVal = $('minutes').val(); //not finding the minutes selected
    alert(minuteVal);
    alert("Sent to the printing holding queue, you may close this app now or carry on using this app, your work will still print out ");
    //location.href = 'index.xhtml';
}
```

I have tried

```
var minuteVal = $('minutes').text();
```

and this returns an empty box. Thanks.

**Edit**

The JavaScript above is found

```
                </h:form>
            </h:body>
        </div>
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        .....
    </script>
</html>
```

at the bottom of the XHTML.

EDIT

here is the source, i don't have a clue what any of this means

```
In how many minutes time would you like to have your job sent to the printer ?
<div class="whiteSpace"></div>
<span id="j_idt8:minutes" class="ui-spinner ui-widget ui-corner-all">
    <input id="j_idt8:minutes_input" name="j_idt8:minutes_input" type="text" class="ui-spinner-input ui-inputfield ui-state-default ui-corner-all" autocomplete="off" value="1" size="1" />
    <a class="ui-spinner-button ui-spinner-up ui-corner-tr ui-button ui-widget ui-state-default ui-button-text-only">
        <span class="ui-button-text">
            <span class="ui-icon ui-icon-triangle-1-n"></span>
        </span>
    </a>
    <a class="ui-spinner-button ui-spinner-down ui-corner-br ui-button ui-widget ui-state-default ui-button-text-only">
        <span class="ui-button-text">
            <span class="ui-icon ui-icon-triangle-1-s"></span>
        </span>
    </a>
</span>
<script id="j_idt8:minutes_s" type="text/javascript">
    PrimeFaces.cw('Spinner', 'widget_j_idt8_minutes', {
        id: 'j_idt8:minutes',
        step: 1.0,
        min: 0.0,
        max: 1000.0,
        behaviors: {
            change: function(event) {
                PrimeFaces.ab({
                    source: 'j_idt8:minutes',
                    event: 'valueChange',
                    process: 'j_idt8:minutes',
                    update: 'j_idt8:NewTime'
                }, arguments[1]);
            }
        }
    });
</script>
<span id="j_idt8:minutes2"></span>
```

EDIT

```
function Thankyou()
{
    var minutesVal = $('#minutes').spinner('value');//not finding the minutes selected
    alert(minutesVal);
    alert("Sent to the printing holding queue, you may close this app now or carry on using this app, your work will still print out ");
    //location.href = 'index.xhtml';
}
```

Now nothing happens, the loading symbol on the mouse comes up but no message box etc

Comment: Where are you including jQuery in your document?  That's a jQuery method.

Comment: i am including it at the bottom under     <script type="text/javascript">

Comment: shouldn't you use $('#minutes').val() ?

Comment: What is that? `<p:spinner>`? Presumably a templating system of some kind?

Comment: Do you have a link to the jQuery code library?  I see you have the script with custom code but what about the jQuery library itself, from a CDN or a local download of it?

Comment: @user2292674 Is it possible for you to generate your javascript from jsp?

Comment: how would i do that ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Grab the first and second spinner from the final source in HTML:

```
var firstSpinner, secondSpinner;
$('input.ui-spinner-input').each(function(index) {
    if(index == 0) {firstSpinner = $(this).val();}
    else if (index == 1) {secondSpinner = $(this).val();} 
});
alert('First spinner: ' + firstSpinner + ' Second spinner: ' + secondSpinner);
```

Comment: Does the alert say "undefined"?

Comment: There is not an alert anymore

Comment: looking at the console when i try to run the js i get the 'Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'spinner''

Comment: sadly i have two spinners on the page :(

Comment: That code is working perfectly for the first spinner, how can i get the value of the 2nd ? (2nd spinner is the spinner above we have been trying to get the value for)

Comment: changed the answer to retrieve both spinner values

Comment: thanks a lot, but i am getting the error: `printServerSide.xhtml:33:31 Expectd, but found alert}` showing an ^ under the a of alert

Comment: Add a closing parentheses an semicolon before the alert, after the closing curly brace

Comment: You are a genius :D all working perfectly, thanks a lot for all your help i could never have done this without you guys :)

Answer (score 4):

The selector `'minutes'` looks for an element with the tag name `'minutes'`, as in `<minutes>`. You want to go by id, which would be `'#minutes'`.

```
var minuteVal = $('#minutes').val();
```

Comment: That as well displays undefined sadly :(

Comment: The `.val()` method is for form elements (inputs, etc.). What sort of html element(s) does the `<p:spinner>` produce?

Comment: I wonder if the selector `'[id$="minutes"]'` or something would work, because of `id` generation

Comment: From a quick Google, it *seems* to be this: http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/spinner.jsf, which *should* produce an `input` element (among others), though it looks ('inspect element') like the `id` will bear only a passing resemblance to the string passed in as the `id`. So @Ian could well be right. Incidentally, I *really* dislike the look of that components system...

Comment: @DavidThomas Yeah! Haha I couldn't remember the name, but PrimeFaces sounds right.

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: Object [id$="minutes"] has no method 'attr

Comment: Perhaps you could update your question to show the actual generated html element(s), instead of just the source JSP? It shouldn't be up to _us_ to go googling the documentation to figure out what gets generated when you can do a simple "View Page Source" in your browser and see it directly. (Remember that JavaScript - including jQuery - is dealing with the html the browser receives, it doesn't know about any server-side JSP code.)

Comment: Added the source, sorry i did not know how to view that before, i do not understand any of  this, all very new ! :)

Answer (score 3):

jQuery selects elements based on css-style selectors; as an example, what you currently have would be selecting a 'minutes' tag, what you need is this:

```
 var minuteVal = $('#minutes').attr("value");
```

On top of that, `value` is not a valid attribute for anything but `input`, `textarea`, and `select` tags, so you either need to use `data-` prefixed attributes for non-standard html attributes, with `.data("value")`, or do something akin to the above.

Comment: That as well displays undefined

Comment: @nnnnnn, and others, I have attempted to fix things.  Sorry on my end.   I used the wrong wording.

Comment: I'll delete my previous comment. I don't know why you're getting downvoted over a minor wording thing like that, especially now that you've fixed it (I didn't downvote).

Comment: @nnnnnn Thank you for that, though if you have any suggestions on how I could improve this further, I'm all ears.

Comment: @Daedalus Well, they aren't using a `<p>` tag. They're using `<p:spinner>`, which is a JSP tag. `p` refers to the alias of the library of tags, and can be generated as anything - even several, nested elements

Comment: @Ian Thank you for the clarification; I've altered the answer slightly to be a slight more.. open in that regard.. at least I hope.  And ya, it would be great to see the actual, generated html instead of the source.

Comment: what do you mean the generated html ?

Comment: @user2292674 The end result that the browser sees. Such as when you 'view source' of the page, or you inspect the element with developer tools.

Comment: Added the source, sorry i did not know how to view that before, i do not understand any of  this, all very new ! :)

Comment: Deleted my comment, since you've fixed.

Comment: @user2292674 Try this: `var minuteVal = $("[id$='minutes']").find("input").val()`